# Vue 3 Composition API (setup lang="ts")

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have my own modal window component. How do I make it global? It is necessary that this component can be called from any application file without import. It is necessary to make it global. Does anyone know how to do this in setup lan ts?

I tried to register the component via component and use. I also tried using `vita.config`. The `TS` code is below:

```
return defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      vue(
        {
          template: {
            compilerOptions:{
              isCustomElement: (tag) => 'my-component'.includes(tag),
            }
          }
        }
      ),
    ],
})
```

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what u want can be done with a Plugin:

https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html

This is an example of a my own code (I use nuxt with vuejs3, if u do so take it as example, otherwise, search in the doc i shared before)

```js
import PopupForm from "~/components/Basicos/PopupForm.vue";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  //Add the global component u wnat to use
  nuxtApp.vueApp
  //Componnetes
    .component("PopupForm", PopupForm)
});
```